# How do I construct an OpenCascade `TopoDS_Shape` which is an identity element of `BRepAlgoAPI_Common`

Tags: c++, boolean-logic, opencascade, csg

I'm trying to use [OpenCascade](https://dev.opencascade.org/)'s [`BRepAlgoAPI_Common`](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_b_rep_algo_a_p_i___common.html) and [`BRepAlgoAPI_Fuse`](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_b_rep_algo_a_p_i___fuse.html) as implementations of "intersection" and "union" operations for [Constructive Solid Geometry (CSG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry).
My solids are represented as instances of [`TopoDS_Shape`](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_topo_d_s___shape.html) (although I'm strictly interested in "Solid" values, so mainly `TopoDS_Solid` and `TopoDS_CompSolid`)

As far as simple operations on finite shapes goes, this is going pretty well.

However, because CSG operations form a [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), I'm interested in constructing identity values for the two CSG operations.

That is, a value `everywhere` for which `intersection(x, everywhere) == x` for all shapes, and a value `nowhere` for which `union(x, nowhere) == x`.

The [documentation for `BRepBuilderAPI_MakeSolid()`](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_b_rep_builder_a_p_i___make_solid.html#details) states that

> An empty solid is considered to cover the whole space

As such, I'd expect that I should be able to construct a value for `everywhere`, (the identity for intersection)  by constructing a `BRepBuilderAPI_MakeSolid`, adding no shells to it, and building the result:

```cpp
    auto everywhere = BRepBuilderAPI_MakeSolid().Shape();
```

However, if I experiment with this, it actually works as the identity for "union" (`nowhere`), and if I try and calculate the intersection of an object with `everywhere` (using `BRepAlgoAPI_Common`), I get an empty result.

Is it possible for me to construct a shape that will work as an identity for "intersection", and if so how?

Comment: I should add that taking the [complement](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/refman/html/class_topo_d_s___shape.html#a9773939e34bd7b5e71fdbc476825a727) of an empty Solid does not result in an identity for intersection, either